# LSTM Layers Structure Query

Tags: machine-learning, keras, lstm

I have a code that works if layers[2] but not layers[3]..
layers[3] gives the error, IndexError: list index out of range

But what does [3] or [2] means?

I thought I am suppose to construct layers[0] > layers[1] > layers[2] according.. why can I have 2 layers[2]

```
def build_model(layers):
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(LSTM(
        input_dim=layers[0],
        output_dim=layers[1],
        return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(LSTM(
        layers[2],
        return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(Dense(
        output_dim=layers[3])) #works if layers[2]
    model.add(Activation("linear"))

    start = time.time()
    model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="rmsprop",metrics=['accuracy'])
    print("Compilation Time : ", time.time() - start)
    return model
```

Comment: `layers` doens't have 4 elements for you to get `layers[3]`. You're already getting the 3 elements with `layers[0]`, `layers[1]`, and `layers[2]`

Comment: Hint: LSTM layers need `input_shape=(timeSteps,input_sim)`

Comment: I agree with @DanielMöller . `[0],[1],[2]` are indexes of the layers you have. Seems that you have 3 layers, as you got an Out Of Range Exception.

Comment: I have 4 columns in my dataframe, the first 3 is used to predict the 4th column, so that is the reason only [0],[1],[2] is able to be used? But why can I have 2 layers[2], will there be a conflict? (Since one is LSTM, one is Dense)